# Adding a blog meta description via Blogger API v 1.0

Tags: java, blogger

How do you add a meta description to a blog post via Blogger API v1.0 ?

Google doesn't help much with the documentation https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/1.0/reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a meta description to a blog post via Blogger API v1.0. Google did not allow this option.